# Como pegar dados no php passados por parâmetro com Angular

Tags: php, angularjs

Preciso pegar 1 dado passado do controller do angular para o meu arquivo php, como faço?

```
app.controller("EditarPerfilCtrl", function ($scope, $http, $window) {

var idempresa = $window.localStorage.getItem('idemp');
var empresa = $window.localStorage.getItem('empresa');
var usuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('usuario');
var idusuario = $window.localStorage.getItem('idusuario');

$scope.empresa = empresa;
$scope.usuario = usuario;

var params = {
    idusuario: idusuario
}

var buscaUsuario = function(){
        $http.get("http://localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/buscaUsuario.php", params).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
}

buscaUsuario();

});
```

php:

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

include_once("con.php");

$pdo = conectar();

$params = $_GET['params'];
print_r($params);
?>
```

Comment: qual o erro apresentado?

Comment: "<br />↵<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: params in <b>/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/buscaUsuario.php</b> on line <b>9</b><br />↵

Comment: Já tentou dar print_r($_GET) só pra ver o que retorna?

Comment: Consegui com a ajuda do cara ai abaixo, mas o problema agora é outro. Aparece isso no console:
""Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" e aponta pra essa linha: $http.get("localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fl‌​uxojoin_2.0/…;, params: params).then(function(data){"

Answer (score 1):

Primeiro, você tem que passar os parâmetros, né?!

Onde tem `params` você tem que dizer o que você quer passar. Mesmo que você tenha criado uma variável com os dados, `params` ainda é um atributo do ***[$http.get](http://techfunda.com/howto/562/http-get-server-request)***.

```
var params = {
    "id-usuario": idusuario
};

var config = {
    params: params
};

var buscaUsuario = function(){
    $http.get("http://localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/buscaUsuario.php", config).then(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
};
```

Então, no PHP, você pode fazer:

```
<?php

//Recebe o ID do $http.get
$id_usuario = $_GET['id-usuario'];

var_dump($id_usuario);
```

Comment: Fiz como vc passou, acima, e aparece a seguinte mensagem no console:
"Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list" e aponta pra essa linha:
$http.get("http://localhost:8888/sistemas/webApps/fluxo_de_caixa/fluxojoin_2.0/php/buscaUsuario.php", params: params).then(function(data){